# Simplifying a proof of Sylow's first theorem

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, sylow-theory

I see a proof of Sylow's first theorem (that Sylow subgroups exists) [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~kpmann/SylowNotes.pdf). I change the proof a little bit when I try to reproduce it, but I am not sure if my proof is correct.

**Theorem.** Let $G$ be a group. $|G|=mp^n,p\nmid m $. ("$|$" means "divides".) Then $\text{Syl}_p(G)\neq \emptyset$.

*My proof.* Let's proceed by induction on the order of the group.

If $|Z(G)|=m_1p^k$, where $k\geq 1$ and $m_1 |m$. By induction hypothesis, $Z(G)$ has a sylow $p$-subgroup of order $p^k$, namely $P$. $Z(G)$ is Abelian, so the choice of $P$ is unique. (I admit we do need to prove some results for Abelian group first.) Therefore, $Z(G) \text{ char }G,P \text{ char }Z(G)$, and due to transitivity of $\text{ char }$, $P \text{ char } G$. Therefore, we can take the quotient group $G/P$. $|G/P|=m_2p^{n-k}$, where $m_1m_2=m$, by Lagrange theorem. By induction hypothesis, $G/P$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P_2/P$ of order $p^{n-k}$.

Now we prove that $P_2\in \text{Syl}_p(G)$. $\forall x\in P_2,\exists r_1, x^{p^{r_1}}\in P$ since $P_2/P$ is a $p$-group. However, $P$ is also a $p$-group, so $\exists r_2, (x^{p^{r_1}})^{p^{r_2}}=x^{p^{r_1+r_2}}=1$, so $P_2$ is also a $p$-group. It's obvious that $|P_2|=p^n$.

The case in which $|Z(G)|$ is not divisible by $p$: I will prove that there exists a proper subgroup whose order is divisible by $p^n$, and apply the induction hypothesis. Suppose not. Then $\forall g\in G$ ,$|N_G(g)|$ is not divisible by $p^n$. Therefore, the length of the conjugate class of $g$, $|G|/|N_G(g)|$ is divisible by $p$. Let $\{C_i\}$ be the set of conjugate classes with length at least $2$. Then
$$
|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum |C_i|, 
$$
which forces $|Z(G)|$ to be divisible by $p$, contradiction.

**Is my proof correct?** It does seem to be essentially the same as the one linked.

EDIT: $N_G(g)$ should really be $C_G(g)$.

Comment: Yes. While there are some differences in the particulars, the proofs are at their core the same. In the case when $p$ divides $|Z(G)|$, both involve picking a normal subgroup of $G$ order divisible by $p$, and, via a quotient group, forming a smaller group to which the induction hypothesis may be applied. In the second case, where $p$ doesn't divide $|Z(G)|$, both use the class equation to establish the existence of a proper subgroup of $G$ to which the induction hypothesis may be applied.

Comment: I also think your proof is essentially the same. Two comments: 1) Using the concept of characteristic subgroups feels a bit too much. Any subgroup of the center is automatically normal, and that's all you need. 2) When applying the class equation you really want the *centralizer* $C_G(g)$. I'm not sure there is such a thing as the normalizer of a single element. To me the notation $N_G(H)$ implies that $H$ is a subgroup as opposed to a random subset.